# Use titlesec from Sublime 2

Tags: titlesec, sublime-text

Sorry for the stupid question.. But how is it possible to use the `titlesec`package of LaTeX from sublime 2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\usepackage{titlesec}`  in the preamble…

Comment: Welcome! Sublime 2 is just an editor, isn't it? So you just use it the way you'd use it in any `.tex` document... (i.e. as Bernard said).

Comment: Sorry, I was really unspecific. My problem was that that was not functioning before, while all other packages were functioning perfectly. I just reinstalled MikTex and now it's all good. Thanks!